# Search for a HTML tag in webpage using a url

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have been working on a project where i have to fetch all the images in a url input given by the user and save a copy of all the images found and selected by the user to his account.
I'm just searching for a better solution here. I couldn't even try anything except saving images from the current page opened in an iframe. 
Please suggest a solution.

Comment: In PHP, [find a DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Do the users have there own directories for images?

Comment: yeah, there is a profile section that i have created where they can browse their directory too.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry i saw in the question *save a copy of all the images found and selected by the user to his account, So by that i see you want to save only selected images what are selected by the user what i posted was incorrect more code below . . .

```
<?php
$allowed_formats  = array("png", "jpg", "gif");//Allowed image formats to save image as
$users_directory = "image-directory";//directory to save the images when user selects image to save

if ( isset( $_POST['view'] ) ) {//If url form submitted 
$users_submitted_url = $_POST['url'];//users submitted url
$ch = curl_init();//Curl the page
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL , $users_submitted_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$web_images_response = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);

preg_match_all('@<img src="http://(.*?)"@', $web_images_response, $imgs);//match only full image links
$image_divs .= '';
foreach($imgs['1'] as $image_url){ 
$image_divs .= "<div><a href='".$PHP_SELF."?url=".$image_url."' target='_blank'><img height='200px' height='200px' src='http://".$image_url."'></a></div>";//make images if clicked use get method to save the image
}


}



if ($_GET["url"] == ""){//If url to save is blank do nothing else save image
}
else{
$split_image = pathinfo($_GET["url"]);
if (in_array($split_image['extension'], $allowed_formats)) {

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL , "http://".$_GET["url"]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$response= curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$file_name = $users_directory."/".$split_image['filename'].".".$split_image['extension'];//save image as file name and extension
$file = fopen($file_name , 'w') or die("X_x");
fwrite($file, $response);
fclose($file);
}
}
?>


<form method="post">
URL:<input name="url" value="http://piic.us/gallery.php" onclick="this.value='';"/>
<input name="view" value="Submit Query" type="submit" />
</form>

<?php echo $image_divs;?>
```

If the user clicks an image it saves to there directory, I hope i got it right this time.

Comment: awesome buddy, i can see the images coming in my directory, but i'm, getting undefined index: extension.

Comment: What do you mean by *undefined index: extension*? like png, gif, jpg etc?